# How do I address plot.new

Tags: r, plot

```
food <- c(5, 8, 15, 20, 4, 18)
barplot(food)
meanValue <- mean(food)
abline(h=meanValue)
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

I'm an R beginner. How do I address this? I see from the other answers that I have to plot it first. But what do I plot? `plot(food)` or `plot(meanValue)`?

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem with the code you provided in your question.

Comment: Could you elaborate in which context this error occurs?

Comment: Pascal - that's it. Ideally I'm supposed to see a plot showing the mean value after the abline command, but not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Weird. Figured it out. I had closed my Quartz windows initially after barplot(). Once I left it open, the error didn't appear. Thanks anyway!